# What is difference between loss function and RMSE in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function

Can somebody explain what is the difference between loss function and RMSE(root mean square error) in Machine Learning?

Comment: RMSE is a loss function, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

The loss function stands for a function of the output of your learning system and the "Ground Truth" which you want to minimize.

In the case of Regression problems one reasonable loss function would be the RMSE.

For cases of Classification the RMSE isn't a good choice of a loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Root mean square error is the square root of difference of your true dependent variable and predicted dependent variable.

Why we do square root?
If we find the difference b/w true and predicted you may get negative values and positive values. If you do a summation of that diff that will be zero which is useless.

The loss function is nothing but just difference b/w true and predicted.

RMSE is calculated if there is a continuous dependent variable (usually in the case of Regression problems).

Comment: Thank you so much Tharun :)

Comment: Not exactly correct: RMSE *is* indeed a loss function, as already pointed out in comments and other answer

Answer (score 0):

RMSE is a specific type of loss function while loss functions are objective functions that are minimized. So, RMSE is a **type** of loss function

What's a loss function? At its core, a loss function is incredibly simple: It's a method of evaluating how well your algorithm models your dataset. If your predictions are totally off, your loss function will output a higher number. If they're pretty good, it'll output a lower number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).